# How I can get an azure management certificate?

Tags: c#, azure, certificate, x509certificate2, azure-management-api

I have a console application running on an Azure cloud service VM that need getting a management certificate.

My certificate is loaded on SETTINGS/CERTIFICATE but what should I do next?

I tried something like this:

```
 X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
 certStore.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
 X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates
      .Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certificateThumb, false);
 X509Certificate2 certificate = certCollection[0];
```

Maybe I don't understand how works SETTINGS/CERTIFICATE  but I only get an error message saying there are no certificate having this thumbprint.

EDIT: I complete my question.
Is this enough to make a declaration in SETTINGS/CERTIFICATE?

Comment: have you tried to lookup in the CurrentUser store?

Comment: @cryptoguy yes i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question.

In fact we have 2 way to use management certificate.

1. create a publishsetting file with the powershell command *get-AzurePublishsettingsFile*. The command adds a .cer certificate in management store as well. We just have to deserialize the base 64 certificate found into the file and add it in the credentials
2. create a certificate with makecert. Load the .cer in the azure management store and the .pfx in the local store from where the client application is installed

some links:

http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/11/programmatically-installing-and-using-your-management-certificate-with-the-new-publishsettings-file/